# how to change default port 8080 of "quarkus keycloak" in windows

Tags: port, keycloak, quarkus

Whenever I am trying to run the command -

```
kc.bat start-dev --http-port="port number
```

its showing some error called

```
unmatched argument at index 3: "port number
```

Answer (score 8):

The property needs to be set in **keycloak.conf** file available under ***keycloak/conf*** folder.
Along with several other properties just add 
**http-port=PORT NUMBER**

and this will work every time.

More info can be found here -> https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config

Answer (score 1):

try this command for changing default port to custom port of Keycloak Quarkus distributor

```
kc.bat start-dev dummy --http-port <port-number>
```

Comment: This is the solution for temporary, means every time stopped the server and again i start the server i was listening on 8080